# Counting occurrences of strings in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My code is supposed to tally up all the times a dinosaur bone is displayed in a .txt file but my code states  that all bones are displayed 0 times.

```
print('Bones found:')
f=open('bones.txt')
bones = {line.replace('\n', ''): 0 for line in f}
for bone in f:
  if bone in bones:
    bones[bone]=bones[bone]+1

for y in bones:
  print(y+':'+str(bones[y]))
```

The bones.txt file is :

```
Ankylosaurus
Pachycephalosaurus
Ankylosaurus
Tyrannosaurus Rex
Ankylosaurus
Struthiomimus
Struthiomimus
```

It says:

```
Bones found:
Ankylosaurus:0
Pachycephalosaurus:0
Tyrannosaurus Rex:0
Struthiomimus:0
```

But supposed to say:

```
Bones found:
Ankylosaurus: 3
Pachycephalosaurus: 1
Tyrannosaurus Rex: 1
Struthiomimus: 2
```

Comment: I'm a beginner. It's my 4th week.

Comment: You've exhausted your file iterator, you can't loop over the file more than once.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin that's fine, in this case, because they are looping over a `dict`.

Comment: Also iterating over the file twice: once in the dict comprehension, a second time in the `for`.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use an iterator (which is obtained by using `open(file.txt)` once. The following code should work for your case. This code makes use of a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is included in the standard python libraries and is designed for counting occurrences of strings.

**By using a Counter**

```
# import the Counter so it can be used
from collections import Counter
# open the text file in read mode, by using this construct, 
# the lock will be released after the with-block to ensure 
# resources are freed correctly
with open("bones.txt") as file:
    # for every line in the file; remove the \n and insert it into the counter
    counts = Counter(line.strip() for line in file)

# print every key in the counter
for dinosaur in counts:
    print("{}: {}".format(dinosaur, counts[dinosaur]))
```

**By using a dictionary**

This code does not use a Counter, but operates exactly the same.

```
# open the text file in read mode, by using this construct, 
# the lock will be released after the with-block to ensure 
# resources are freed correctly
with open("bones.txt") as file:
    # create a dictionary to store the counts
    counts = dict()
    # iterate over every line in the file
    for line in file:
        # remove the \n from the line
        stripped = line.strip()

        if stripped in counts:
            # key already exists -> increment it
            counts[stripped] += 1
        else:
            # key doesn't exist -> add it
            counts[stripped] = 1

# print every key in the counts dictionary
for dinosaur in counts:
    print("{}: {}".format(dinosaur, counts[dinosaur]))
```

**Output**

```
Pachycephalosaurus: 1
Struthiomimus: 2
Ankylosaurus: 3
Tyrannosaurus Rex: 1
```

Comment: @biwwibourdi I updated my answer to include a non-Counter answer too